# How to display all elements in an ArrayList except one element?

Tags: java, arraylist, element

I want to display all elements in an `ArrayList`, except element 10 (which is the word "will"). How do I do this? When I run the below code it shows nothing.

```
 private void practiceButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     ArrayList <String> practice1 = new ArrayList();
     Collections.addAll(practice1, "If", "she", "boarded", "the", "flight"
                        , "yesterday", "at",  "10:00,", "she", "will", "be"
                        , "here", "anytime", "now.");
     contentTextPane.setText(practice1.get(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+11+12+13));
 }
```

Comment: Your get statement is equivalent to `practice1.get(81)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
practice1.get(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+11+12+13)
```

Does not do what you think it does.  This will compute the value of 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + 13, then look up that entry in the `ArrayList`.  Since your `ArrayList` doesn't have this many elements, it will throw an `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

If you want to display everything except the tenth element, try using a loop:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < practice1.size(); i++) {
    if (i != 10) {
        builder += practice1.get(i);
    }
}
contextTextPane.setText(builder.toString());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the 10th element of a list like this:

```
someList.remove(10);
```

You can concatenate each element of the list like this:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
for (String thisString : someList) {
    text.append(thisString).append(" ");
}

// test it
System.out.println(text.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

It shows nothing because you are retrieving an element from the list by using a syntax which doesn't exist

```
0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+11+12+13
```

is just evaluated as the sum of all the numbers and then used to get an element which will be outside bounds.

What you need to do is something like

```
String r = "";
for (int i = 0; i < practice.size(); ++i)
  if (i != 10)
    r += practice.get(i);

contentTextPane.setText(r);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void practiceButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    ArrayList <String> practice1 = new ArrayList();

    Collections.addAll(practice1, "If", "she", "boarded", "the", "flight", "yesterday", "at",  
 "10:00,", "she", "will", "be", "here", "anytime", "now.");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < practice1.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 10) {
            continue;
        }
        sb.append(practice1.get(i));
        if (i != practice1.size()-1) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
    }

    contentTextPane.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `practice1.get(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+11+12+13)` gives you the object in practice1 at index 81, which is equal to the sum of the argument values, throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Instead, you should iterate through the values and add them to a StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < practice1.size(); i++) {
    if (i != 10) {
        sb.append(practice1.get(i));
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}
contentTextPane.setText(sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1));
```

Comment: +1 for use of StringBuilder (faster) - you can also use *foreach* : for (String string : practice1) { ..

Comment: It's less correct to filter out the tenth object using a foreach, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
practice1.get(0) + practice1.get(1) + ...
```

... instead of this:

```
contentTextPane.setText( practice1.get(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+11+12+13) );
```

Though it would be best if you used a loop.